# Building/Compiling C-code on another machine via bsub

Tags: c++, c, makefile, lsf

We have a server that we use to build our software and sometimes it is overloaded. I was told that our servers network configured in such a way that I could build/compile our source code on another machine that might be not so overloaded at that time via **bsub**.

So from the directory where my Makefile (/home/username/workspace) is, I enter:

```
$ bsub make clean
```

It seems that this command successfully send *'make clean'* to another machine because a few minutes later I got notification via email. However, it seems that *'make clean'* has failed. This is what the email says:

```
  Job <make clean> was submitted from host <myserver> by user <username> in cluster <Cluster_Name>.
  Job was executed on host(s) <hostname>, in queue <long>, as user <username> in cluster <Cluster_Name>.
  ...
  ...
  </home/username> was used as the home directory.
  </tmp> was used as the working directory.
  ...
  ...
  make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
```

So, it appears that **/tmp** was used as the working directory instead of my /home/username/workspace where the Makefile is.

Now the questions are:

1. How do I make my workspace as the working directory? **OR**
2. How do I copy all the necessary files to the /tmp? **OR**
3. Maybe I'm doing this all wrong?

I don't have any background at all on distributed computing or related fields, so I might not be asking the right questions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with languages or build systems.  It's all about your job management system and the configuration of your particular cluster.  Have you considered reading [the `bsub` manual page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSETD4_9.1.2/lsf_command_ref/bsub.1.html)?  The `-cwd` option looks promising, provided that your cluster is configured suitably.